# Update all except last two?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `CTE` that looks like the following:

```
;with cte as  
(  
    SELECT  WeekNum
    FROM MonitorTable 
    GROUP BY WeekNum
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN IsProcessed = 1 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END) = 8
    order by WeekNum
) 
update MonitorTable 
set ReadToGrid = 0 
where WeekNum in (select WeekNum from cte)
```

The issue here is that it's updating everything. Since there always has to be two left, I can only update everything except the last.

So let's say that CTE returns the following:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I cannot update everything; would need to update everything except the last two (1, 2, 3, 4).

So how can I modify the script so that it updates everything except the last two rows?

Thanks.

Comment: change the `where` condition to `where WeekNum in (select WeekNum-2 from cte)`?

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE WeekNum <= (SELECT MAX(WeekNum)-2 FROM cte)`

Answer (score 1):

Without data I cant test the exact syntax but the idea will work:

```
Select WeekNum, Row_Number() Over (Order By WeekNum Desc) RowNum
From
(
SELECT  WeekNum
    FROM MonitorTable 
    GROUP BY WeekNum
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN IsProcessed = 1 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END) = 8
)
update MonitorTable set ReadToGrid = 0 where WeekNum in (select WeekNum from cte Where RowNum > 2)
```

Comment: Windowing functions: the solution to every problem

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between vkp's suggestion and your code?

Comment: This code will work even if there are missing numbers which may never be the case in your situation or may eventually happen.  I like to future proof if its not much extra work.  For example if you have 1,2,3,4,6.  Using weeknum minus two will return -1, 0, 1, 2, 4 which will omit 6 and give the others.  Using row_number on the same data will return 1,2,3